# Button is clicked but doesn't proceed to another page- Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-ide

This is strange. The button is clicked but doesn't redirect to another page.

This is my method :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Phone Number'])[1]/following::button[1]")).Click();
```

or

```
var Proceed = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'Proceed')]"));
Proceed.Click();
```

This how button look in HTML:

```
 <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-xs-12 no-padding-sides">
       <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4 no-padding-sides bottom-actions">
<button _ngcontent-c4="" class="btn custom-btn custom-blue" type="submit"> Proceed </button>
    <button _ngcontent-c4="" class="btn custom-btn custom-grey" type="button"> Cancel</button></div>
    </div>
```

N.B: I tested the same scenario on selenium IDE and selenium webdriver both have same problem.

Comment: How you ensure it that Button is clicked ? Are you sure ?

Comment: i just  tried to click on the button with empty fields and checked the validation and worked normally

Comment: if you are trying to fill up form and then proceeding to the next page, for debugging purpose put some wait/pause between the form fill up and clicking of button. Also make sure the DOM does not change on filling up the form , making sure the empty form and filled form has same locators for button.

Comment: nothing worked man

Comment: still no answer here

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
var Proceed = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(.,'Proceed')]"));
```

or

```
var Proceed = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='custom-blue']"));
```

If those don't work, please post some more HTML.